# Ruby on Rails rooting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Im trying to create simple Ruby on Rails REST API.

app/controllers/api/vi/product_controller.rb

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProductController < ApplicationController::API
            def index
                render json: {message: 'Welcome!'}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get '/product', to: 'product_controller#index', as: 'product'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run project on localhost, I get `uninitialized constant Api::V1::ApplicationController` routing error. Can anyone help to such Ruby on Rails newbie as I am?

Comment: change this line and try once:`class ProductController < ApiController`

Comment: Error: `uninitialized constant ApiController`

Comment: Where is `ApplicationController::API` come from?

Comment: I don't know... I did this just like tutorial said. I thought that it is some kind of generic class...

Answer (score 1):

you just need to create a folder inside controllers called api and a v1 folder inside api.
You should provide all the controllers inside v1 folder.

In your app/controllers/api/v1/product_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ProductController < ApplicationController
    def index
      render json: {message: 'Welcome!'}
    end
end
```

In your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get '/product', to: 'product_controller#index', as: 'product'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you nested the route, so it should be '/api/v1/product`

if you run `rake routes` from your console, you will get a list of all available routes.

for more information about routing and nested routes, have a look at [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: `get '/product', to: 'product#index', as: 'product'`? Still the same error with this line of code...

Comment: `rake routes` output: `api_v1_product GET  /api/v1/product(.:format) api/v1/product#index`

Answer (score 0):

change this and try:

```
module Api
    module V1
      class ProductController < ApplicationController
            def index
                render json: {message: 'Welcome!'}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @JacobJones oops.. what is the path of your controller

Comment: My controller path: app/controllers/api/v1/product_controller.rb

Comment: @JacobJones please add your application controller code here